# How do I 'upload' executables to a Nintendo DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds, backwards-compatibility, nes

My girlfriend really likes old school NES games, and she has a DS. I figured the best way to get her games would be to install a NES emulator like NESDS on her DS.  Having no experience with this, I googled for instructions, but they are a little beyond my understanding.  I didn't think there was a way to 'upload' executables or files to the DS, but maybe I'm wrong.

Essentially, how do I get NESDS onto a DS system?
Secondly, how do I get ROMs onto the system as well (I assume the same way).

Comment: Stealing is bad, m'kay.

Answer (score 2):

You have to purchase some sort of [Nintendo DS storage device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_DS_storage_devices). There are... a lot of choices, and I don't have experience with the large majority of them. I'd imagine that anything in the "Third generation" category on that article should be more than capable.

Make sure you do a bit of research into the one you pick before you actually buy it, specifically regarding compatibility with the type of DS she has. The newer DSes (DSi, XL) have some protections in their firmware to try to prevent these types of things from working, so it may be difficult or even impossible to get a particular card to work on some DS models.

Comment: Wow. One step closer yet I'm still baffled :)  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I could try to give some more information, there just really isn't much to it once you've gotten one working. Picking a device and setting it up is the most complex part (and it differs somewhat for every device), but once you're past that point it's basically just copying files onto a micro-SD card.

Comment: Ok, I'll figure out the exact DS and see how far I can get.  Thanks!